# Hartshorne: Definition of $K^*$ where $K$ a function field of scheme.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, field-theory, notation

Let $X$ be a noetherian integral separated scheme which is regular of codimension one. Let $K$ be the function field of $X$.

Now let $f \in K^*$, (I am interpreting  $K^*$ to be the set of field automorphisms from $K \to K$) be any nonzero rational function on $X$.

I am very confused by the statement after the parenthesis. I thought a rational function on $X$ was an element of the function field $K$.

How can $f \in K$ and $f \in K^{*}$ ?

It is likely that I am not interpreting $K^*$ correctly.

Comment: This is really a general piece of notation for fields (or even rings). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_(ring_theory)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The intended interpretation is that $K^*=K\setminus\{0\}$ (the group of multiplicative units of $K$), so an element of $K^*$ is just a nonzero element of $K$.  Another common notation for this set is $K^\times$.

Comment: Oh! I had not seen that notation before.